# ¿ Cómo puedo visualizar una página con AddEventListener click?

Tags: javascript, html, css, eventos

Estoy haciendo un C.V. web, y la idea es que su contenido vaya apareciendo en cascada a medida que haces click.

El problema, es que no encuentro forma de que el contenido se vaya mostrando según quiero. No sé porqué.

Éste es mi código:

```
function visibilizar_pagina(){

  if (document.body.style.visibility == "visible") {

    document.getElementById("titulo").style.display = "block"
    
  } else if (document.getElementById("titulo").style.display == "block"){

    document.getElementById("presentacion").style.display = "block";

  } else if (document.getElementById("presentacion").style.display == "block") {

    document.getElementById("informacion").style.display = "block";

  } else if(document.getElementById("informacion").style.display == "block") {

    document.getElementById("menu").style.display = "visible";

  } else {

  }
  
  }

document.addEventListener("click", function(){

  visibilizar_pagina();

  }
  
)
```

Comment: Cuando dices que no se muestra como quieres, ¿A qué te refieres?

Comment: La idea es que al hacer click, se visualice el título, al hacer click nuevamente lo haga la presentación, y así sucesivamente... pero se traba en el título.

Comment: Te he dejado una respuesta. Si tienes dudas, puedes dejar un comentario pidiendo aclaraciones y, si mi respuesta te es de utilidad, no olvides marcarla como aceptada empleando el check debajo del contador de votos.

Comment: Sé más claro con el resultado que quieres obtener. Si es necesario agrega una imagen de ejemplo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estás cerca de lograrlo. Permíteme orientarte un poco.

La idea es que deseas ir mostrando elementos html uno detrás de otro cada vez que haces click en el documento.

Lo primero que debes hacer es ocultar todos los elementos, ya que no puedes mostrar algo que ya es visible. Te propondré un ejemplo donde asigno cada elemento a una variable, de esta forma:

```
let titulo        = document.getElementById("titulo");
let presentacion  = document.getElementById("presentacion");
let informacion   = document.getElementById("informacion");
let menu          = document.getElementById("menu");
```

Y, ya con cada elemento en una variable, será más fácil operar sobre ellos, y te evitas repetir código de forma innecesaria. Ahora, vamos a ocultarlos:

```
titulo.style.display        = "none";
presentacion.style.display  = "none";
informacion.style.display   = "none";
menu.style.display          = "none";
```

Con eso, ahora todos están ocultos. Lo que falta es que se vayan mostrando uno detrás de otro.

Tu enfoque se acerca, pero no es la forma correcta, te propongo lo siguiente:

```
Si:       titulo esta oculto:       muestra titulo
Sino: Si: presentacion esta oculto: muestra presentacion
Sino: Si: informacion  esta oculto: muestra informacion
Sino: Si: menu esta oculto:         muestra menu
```

Te dejo un ejemplo de como queda en código:

<sub>Haz click en `Ejecutar` para probar este código.</sub>

```js
let titulo        = document.getElementById("titulo");
let presentacion  = document.getElementById("presentacion");
let informacion   = document.getElementById("informacion");
let menu          = document.getElementById("menu");

titulo.style.display        = "none";
presentacion.style.display  = "none";
informacion.style.display   = "none";
menu.style.display          = "none";

function visibilizarPagina()
{
    if (titulo.style.display == "none")
    {
        titulo.style.display = "block";
    }
    else
    if (presentacion.style.display == "none")
    {
        presentacion.style.display = "block";
    }
    else
    if (informacion.style.display == "none")
    {
        informacion.style.display = "block";
    }
    else
    if (menu.style.display == "none")
    {
        menu.style.display = "block";
    }
}

document.addEventListener("click", function()
{
    visibilizarPagina();
});
```

```html
<span id="titulo">Titulo</span>
<span id="presentacion">Presentacion</span>
<span id="informacion">Informacion</span>
<span id="menu">Menu</span>
```

Comment: No es buena idea alinear el código horizontalmente (no confundir con identación). Clean Code de Robert C. Martin, Página 87.

Comment: No es que no sea buena idea. Es cuestión de gustos. Bob, solo dice que al formatear el código con los idea actuales, se pierde esa alineación y que al final, gasta tiempo para nada.

Comment: Me sirvió mucho para ser más ordenado, pero aún no lo logro... ahora me abre la página y directamente desplega todo de una... No sé si sera el problema el HTML, ya que por ejemplo titulo es un h1, luego presentacion e información son párrafos, y menú un menú...

Comment: @OscarBalbuena Pulsa en [Editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/580614/edit) para editar tu pregunta y agrega tu HTML.